# Unable to retrieve facebook feed with valid IDs

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been on this for a few hours now, i've read the docs related to what i'm trying to achieve and everything looks right... But it's not working.
I'm simply trying to retrieve a facebook page's feed (3 lasts posts) on my website.
So i'm doing :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v17.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

With FACEBOOK_APP_ID being the app ID that we can find (also) in the url of the app (example : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/FACEBOOK_APP_ID/dashboard/

Then in an external JS file (that is logging FB correctly, I do :

```
FB.api('/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID/feed', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

with FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID being the page ID that we can find in the about section of the said page.

Is there something I'm missing here ? The doc is NOT talking about anything else...
I'm getting this as error :
`(#200) Provide valid app ID`

Thanks !

Comment: _"The doc is NOT talking about anything else..."_ - of course it is. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#readperms: _"If you do not own or manage the Page, you will need: The Page Public Content Access Feature"_ - "proof" that you own or manage the page could only come in the form of a user or page access token - which you don't appear to be using there.

Comment: So this can only count as "public" access, and for that your app would have to get reviewed & the mentioned feature approved - which likely won't happen in your scenario, because the use case of that feature is limited to _"provid[ing] competitive benchmark analysis."_

Comment: @CBroe Indeed, I am not using a page access token because I did not find a place where they explain where to specifiy that information in the called FB function...

Comment: @CBroe They are not specifying any access token in any of the code example for the javascript SDK, I saw that they do it for other languages, but how is a newbie supposed to guess how to add the parameter ( and if he has to if it's not said ? )

Comment: You do not _want_ to use a page access token here to begin with - because that would mean, you'd have to expose it in publicly available client-side code. (Unless you had users log in to your app, to show them content of pages _they_ manage, but that does not appear to be the situation here.) You will need to do this on the server side.

Comment: _"but how is a newbie supposed to guess how to add the parameter"_ - they're not supposed to guess anything, but read the documentation :-)  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/: _"One parameter of note is `access_token` which you can use to make an API call with a Page access token."_ (That would apply to the mentioned scenario where you _get_ a page access token from your site's user, to show content from their own pages. But as said, in your scenario here, you have to do the whole thing server-side to begin with.)

Comment: Alright, thank you for all the informations and for your time @CBroe, I never lended on this page although I did do a lot of searches for additional informations regarding this ;(